# How to connect with SSL to HTTPS server in Python 2.7.10+ and make certificate trusted?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, https, certificate

I wan to connect to https server using ssl with certificate verification and host name validation (do not suggest to switch off verification since it working). How to do it with this code?

```
import ssl
import socket

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = True
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
                           server_hostname='adwords.google.com')
conn.connect(('adwords.google.com', 443))
```

Instead of connection there is exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Crezary Wagner/PycharmProjects/learn-adwords/src/03_ssl.py", line 16, in <module>
    conn.connect(('adwords.google.com', 443))
  File "C:\root\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 844, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\root\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 835, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\root\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It is clear for me that certificate can not be verified as trusted but how to make this certificate trusted in Python 2.7.10+ and connect?

I want setup it in system not in context if it possible.

Comment: Have you looked at using `requests` instead ? `response = requests.get('https://adwords.google.com', verify=False)`

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
response = requests.get('https://adwords.google.com', verify=False)
print response.content
```